# In Typescript how to promisify a function while binding with type safety?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-s3

Consider the following promisification:

```
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk'
import { promisify } from 'util'

const s3 = new S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' })
const getObject = promisify<S3.GetObjectRequest, S3.GetObjectOutput>(
  s3.getObject
)
```

This works fine, except that you'll get errors like `TypeError: this.makeRequest is not a function` because `s3.getObject` is now bound to the wrong `this` scope. However, this:

```
const getObject = promisify<S3.GetObjectRequest, S3.GetObjectOutput>(
  s3.getObject.bind(s3)
)
```

Destroys type safety and will error out: `Unsafe use of expression of type 'any'.` (assuming you use strict mode).

So how can I promisify something like s3's `getObject` in Typescript?

Comment: `() => s3.getObject()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pass another function that calls `s3.getObject()` without having to bind it. Using arrow functions you can do this with very little additional code.

```
const getObject = promisify<S3.GetObjectRequest, S3.GetObjectOutput>(
  name => s3.getObject(name)
)
```

However, the AWS SDK operator functions generally have a `.promise` method that returns a promise rather than you having to promisify manually.

```
s3.getObject(name).promise();
```

Comment: Really like the `.promise`!